# NPOI AutoSizeColumn not resizing correctly

Tags: c#, xlsx, npoi

I've put the .AutoSizeColumn right before the write Method

```
int numberOfColumns = sheet.GetRow(rowcount - 1).PhysicalNumberOfCells;
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
{
    sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);
    GC.Collect();
} 

using (var fileData = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\Contatti.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
   wb.Write(fileData);
}
```

[this is an example of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjE7Q.png)

Comment: How is `sheet.GetRow(rowcount - 1).PhysicalNumberOfCells;` giving you column count?

Comment: rowcount is the variable i use to count the number of row.
- 1 because i set rowcount++; in each loop and i want to get the last "full" row
[Link to image](http://i.imgur.com/LiowsKq.png)

Comment: Does the cell contain formula? What's the benefit or GC.Collect? `i <= numberOfColumns` should be `i < numberOfColumns` as you are starting from 0. btw I've used EPPlus instead of NPOI and found it to be better.

Answer (score 2):

The problem also migh be, that `PhysicalNumberOfCells` can return 1, even if you have a cell lets say in 'Z' column. There is `LastCellNum` property,you i instead of `PhysicalNumberOfCells`:

```
        int lastColumNum = sheet.GetRow(0).LastCellNum;
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastColumNum; i++)
        {
            sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);
            GC.Collect();
        }

        using (var fileData = new FileStream(@"D:\Contatti.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
        {
            wb.Write(fileData);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, i've put it for all columns, not only for the first one.
I'll edit the question to be more clear

Comment: @VDN this is a better fit for comment as it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @Nimesh, I edited my answer, so now it looks more like an answer :)

Comment: I still have the problem. It's the first time i'm using .xlsx, usually i create .xls files without resize problems.
Maybe i've to set a default cell style?

Comment: one more thing you can try is to get the `LastCellNum` of each row, not only the first one as in my answer. Or at least the `LastCellNum` of the row you have problem with

Comment: @Derpzilla Can you also update which libraries are you using? I believe NPOI has multiple libraries for different document types (xls|xlsx).

Comment: That "GC.Collect();" makes me feel this is an incomplete/invalid solution. 100 cols => GC collections